# check availability of room in hotel

Tags: php, sql

There are two tables in my database. First table is room and second table is reservation. In my room table

```
id room_no type rate
1  13       1b  1000
2  14       2b  2000
3  15       3b  3000
4  16       1b  1000
5  17       2b  2000
6  18       3b  3000
```

In my reservation table

```
id room_no check_in     check_out
1   13     23-2-2016     24-2-2016
2   14     24-2-2016     25-2-2016
1   13     25-2-2016     26-2-2016
1   13     27-2-2016     29-2-2016
1   13     1-3-2016      2-3-2016
1   13     7-3-2016      7-3-2016

"SELECT room_no,type,rate 
             FROM room 
             WHERE room_no not in 
             (select IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(room_no),0) 
             FROM reservation 
             WHERE check_out >= '$check_in' AND check_in <= '$check_out')"
```

when I select a date 24-2-2016 to 27-2-2016  then it display

```
room_no check_in     check_out

  14     24-2-2016     25-2-2016
  15     25-2-2016     26-2-2016
  16     27-2-2016     29-2-2016
  17     1-3-2016      2-3-2016
  18     7-3-2016      7-3-2016
```

but I want all available rooms.

Comment: you should just compare with checkout date and current date..

Comment: I select the date in form by date picker text box .so when i select the date 24-2-2016 to 27-2-2016 so it display room_no 14 ,15,16,17 and 18 but i want only room_no which is not between these date. I mean available room

Answer (score 4):

To get occupied rooms for the period specified, i.e `'2016-02-27'-'2016-02-24'`, you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT room_no
FROM reservation
WHERE check_in <= '2016-02-27' AND check_out >= '2016-02-24'
```

**Output:**

```
room_no
=======
13
14
```

To get available rooms you can use the previous query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM room
WHERE room_no NOT IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT room_no
   FROM reservation
   WHERE check_in <= '2016-02-27' AND check_out >= '2016-02-24')
```

**Output:**

```
id, room_no, type, rate
=======================
3,   15,     3b,   3000
4,   16,     1b,   1000
5,   17,     2b,   2000
6,   18,     3b,   3000
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f3698/1)

Comment: This query will return error if there is no room available in `reservation`. Please use `IFNULL` condition.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer No, this is not correct. If reservation is empty, then the query will return all rooms.

Comment: If reservation is empty then what should happen with `NOT IN ()`?

Comment: @Mr.Engineer Have a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3866e1/1) for a demo of this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `LEFT JOIN` should do the trick without using a subquery.

Something like this :

```
SELECT 
    room.room_no,
    room.`type`,
    room.rate,
    COUNT(reservation.room_no) AS countReservation
FROM 
    room
LEFT JOIN reservation
    ON (room.room_no = reservation.room_no) 
        AND (check_in <= '2016-02-24' AND check_out >= '2016-01-27')
GROUP BY 
    room.room_no
HAVING 
    countReservation = 0
```

An other advantage in this query is the extra column `countReservation` that will even tell you if you have 1 or more reservations for the for the given timeframe for each room.

Comment: Dear Benjamin C...The query is working but what is the different between your query and  Giorgos Betsos query ..i didn't  understand what are you trying to say..please explain me properly....thanks

Comment: Well there are a few differences. Generally using joins is faster than using a subquery (a `SELECT` clause inside a `SELECT` clause). Also a `NOT IN(...)` condition is not fast either because the server has to index the result of the subquery and check for the opposite of it after.

FYI I don't have links confirming my assumptions, it's only from personal experience on some past projects with medium-sized database (e.g. 140k contacts rows and 70k companies rows).

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
"SELECT room_no, type, rate 
         FROM room 
         WHERE room_no not in 
         (select room_no FROM reservation 
         WHERE  ('$check_in' BETWEEN check_in AND check_out) AND ('$check_out' BETWEEN check_in AND check_out))"
```

I don't know if the query is correct, but you surely have to check for between.
You can't just test for check_out > than date, and check_in < date. IF you have multiple reservations this will give you Errors!!

Comment: quite possible, you have to compare Dates, you will have to add some date functions. Anyway updated the query a bit, but you will have to invest some work too ;)